# matlabfrag and pstool

Tags: pdfcrop, pstool

I am trying to include figures generated by matlabfrag through pstool.

But with no luck up to this point.

A similar problem is explained on the matlab file exchange and the creater of the matlabfrag package suggested to use

> crop=preview

in the latex file. But I did not really understand where this should be used, basically. Basically, matlabfrag package generates an eps and a text file to be included in the latex code.

[The discussion on file exchange](https://nl.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/21286-matlabfrag)

See the comments from Charlie and Zebb Prime. Any idea on what they mean?

Comment: You posted a dud link. Somebody corrected it for you. You then rolled back their correction, despite the fact that nothing else in your question was touched. This was fixed. I've rolled back to the fixed version. If you don't want to include a working link, don't include a link at all. It makes no sense to include one which doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: I'm not going to go through all that trying to figure out what Charlie and Zebb Prime said, though. At a guess, I'd say you should add this as an option to either a package or your class, depending on the context and details. If you provide a minimal example, you'll stand a better chance of getting help as people will have a clue what you're doing.